# record daily internet bandwidth usage

Tags: internet, bandwidth

I am using internet connection with data cap. I want to record my daily internet usage in a file, is there any tool for this or perhaps you can suggest a script that would run as daemon?

(I am not pro in bash scripting or with linux administrating software so a simple script will be recommended)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/), which keeps track of daily stats for the last 30 days, and is available in the Ubuntu/Debian (and probably many more) repos.

Just install it and use it like `vnstat -i wlan0 -h`:

```
 wlan0                                                                    14:47 
  ^                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                           r                 
  |                                                     r     r  r     r        
  |                                                     rt r  rt rt    r        
 -+---------------------------------------------------------------------------> 
  |  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14    

 h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB) 
15          0          0    23          0          0    07          0          0
16          0          0    00          0          0    08     19,287      7,859
17          0          0    01          0          0    09      6,550      3,231
18          0          0    02          0          0    10     65,500      9,216
19          0          0    03          0          0    11     17,491      7,502
20          0          0    04          0          0    12      5,158      2,503
21          0          0    05          0          0    13     15,034      3,493
22          0          0    06          0          0    14      4,284      2,503
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat), which keeps record of data usage for each interface you enable it on.  You can view detailed records in varying precision from monthly up to hourly (for the last 24 hours).  One very useful thing about vnstat is that it does not require root access to view records.  Most distros seem to have it in their repos, so you should be able to install with

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

-or-

```
sudo yum install vnstat
```

- To enable on an interface: `vnstat --enable -i eth0`
- To view a certain interface: `vnstat -i eth0`

You can add the `-m`, `-w`, `-d`, or `-h` flags to show monthly, weekly, daily, or hourly records, respectively.

If you want to save the logs to a file (which could be useful since vnstat drops old logs from its database), you can use `vnstat --dumpdb` which will output vnstat's current logs.

Comment: it gives me error with `vnstat --enable eth0` 'unknown parameter eth0'

Comment: You need to replace that with the name of the network interface you want to view.

Comment: i did, i wanted to monitor eth0, something is wrong with your command i guess, besides eth0

Comment: Sorry, I typed the command wrong. You need to run `vnstat --enable -i eth0`